# AVAudioPlayer is not working in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have passed button tag to another Viewcontroller.
It's passed but when I'm calling any another method like play audio play on that selected button, player not working...

I have tried below code :
It passes id of button clicked to the other view. Where I build player and and based on button id I want to play a poem on other view and control functions like volume control, progressbar, duration, play, push, next, etc...
While I'm giving a method to a particular button id to play poem it is not working...

This below code for play a poem in another view where I build player.
    `

```
- (IBAction)btnpoemclicked:(id)sender {
    btnPressed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)[sender tag]];

NSLog(@"selected poem -%@",btnPressed);

    PlayerController *pl=[[PlayerController alloc] init];
    pl.btnPressed=btnPressed;
    [pl setBtnPressed:pl.btnPressed];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"player"  sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: have you found solution

Comment: Can you post your code that implement player?

Comment: The issue may be in you player implementation.

Comment: spelling, tags and code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Implement your button action like,

```
- (IBAction)buttonPoemClicked:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Player" sender:sender];
}
```

Pass your value by implementing prepareForSegue,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Player"]) {

      PlayerController *playerController = (PlayerController *)segue.destinationViewController;
      playerController.pressedButtonTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)[sender tag]];
    }
}
```

Additional Note : Try to make your variable/class names little more understandable or try to follow apple recommended naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass values in `prepareForSegue` when using `Segues`.
Update your code like

```
- (IBAction)btnPoemClicked:(id)sender {
    btnPressed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)[sender tag]];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"player"  sender:self];
}
```

And then In `prepareForSegue` pass the values to `destinationViewController` like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"player"]) {
        PlayerController *playerController = (PlayerController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        playerController.btnPressed = btnPressed;
    }
}
```